# Hi, I want to know how can we insert binary data between a binary string in python 3.7?

Tags: string, binary

So, here is something I want to do;

```
binary_string_data_input = '00 AE 65 67 32 2F 33 3A 54 20 46'
```

and I want to insert the following bytes BETWEEN the string like this:

```
binary_string_data_output = '00 AE 65 67 **55 06 33 55 FF** 32 2F 33 3A 54 20 46'
```

Help would be much appreciated thanks!

Comment: Make a new string. Do you always split in the same place?

Comment: Give it a try and show your [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can split (or *slice*) to get the first part:

```
>>> string_data_input[:12]
'00 AE 65 67 '
```

and similarly the last part:

```
>>> string_data_input[12:]
'32 2F 33 3A 54 20 46'
```

So, you can join these with your new "inner" part:

```
>>> string_data_input[:12] + '55 06 33 55 FF ' + string_data_input[12:]
'00 AE 65 67 55 06 33 55 FF 32 2F 33 3A 54 20 46'
```

Comment: you method works but I am not able to save the file.
I have a pre exising file, I need to make the change and then save the file, so that in the saved file I can actually see the change. Right now I am just able to see the change in my python terminal.

Comment: It's hard to add things in the middle of a file. Save a new file, with the change- if that works, then delete the old file and rename the new one?